# Why is Windows first boot time in the morning twice as long as subsequent boots overday?

Tags: windows-10, boot, ssd

On my laptop, I found a weird cycle of boot times.

When I start my laptop in the morning, for the first time in the day, it takes relatively long time to start (last BIOS time 4.7s - 5.8s). Then I shut it down by using Windows shutdown -menu. Starting it again after 1 - 2 hours later, it boots faster, with last BIOS time 2.9s - 3.0s. I start it and shut down ~2 to 3 times after this, and it is has around the same BIOS time. Then I go to bed.

When I start my laptop again the next morning after waking up, it takes a long time again, with last bios time 4.7s - 5.8s. Then the whole cycle repeats.

Why is this happening? Is this common or normal?

Laptop specs and info for context:

- AMD Ryzen 7 5700u octa-core CPU
- 16 GB DDR4 3200 MHz RAM
- 512 GB SSD Storage
- Windows 10
- WSL feature turned on, but no distro installed

Is the WSL optional feature the reason behind this?

Please let me know if this is normal/common.
Thank you!

Comment: @Peregrino69 thanks for responding! I use the shutdown option in the start menu.

Comment: Is the difference that of cold boot versus warm *reboot*? Note that 5 seconds boot is excellent.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the comment. There is probably a 2 second difference. Also, the entire boot takes around 8 seconds on average. Is it fast?

Comment: Much faster than mine, but that probably relates to the number of startup apps.

Comment: Well I have only 3 startup apps, those which are absolutely essential.